# Is there a way to auto populate promo code programmatically in redeem code text box android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-billing

I have integrated Android Google play billing library 4.0.0 in my app. Created a subscription and created a Custom Promo Code for that subscription. Everything works fine but currently I have to select redeem code in the app and apply this custom code to get the offer.

Is there a way to auto populate promo code programmatically for a specific subscription in redeem code text box? Without the user entering it manually.

I checked the documentation from this link and the deep link but didn't find anything related to auto populate promo code for subscription within the app.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo

Comment: did you find an answer to this?